# Calculation of cells based on values in rows before and after - r or python

Tags: python, r

I collect samples of greenhouse gases in glass vials, which are analyzed in a gas chromatograph. In each analysis, standard gases of known concentration are used as a basis to calculate the actual concentration of the gas samples. The standard gases (STD) are dispersed throughout the samples collected in the field. See layout example:

[GC layout with standard gas and field samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfkVe.png)

To calculate the final gas concentration of each vial, I need the average value of the standard gases BEFORE and AFTER the concentration in question.

For example, using the following data: To calculate a new value ("CO2 conc" to be written in a new column) for samples in rows 5-19, I need to average the "CO2 area" values of the "STD" samples BEFORE (rows 1-4) and AFTER (rows 20-23) the samples themselves, then multiply that average by "CO2 area" for each sample and write that value to the new column, "CO2 conc".

```
pos chamber time    sample id   CO2 area    CO2 conc
1           STD 3800.9564
2           STD 3798.167
3           STD 3790.841
4           STD 3798.7983
5   B1  0   B1-300-0    5809.8816
6   B1  5   B1-300-5    6533.1388
7   B1  10  B1-300-10   7290.8798
8   B2  0   B2-300-0    5585.4023
9   B2  5   B2-300-5    5756.92
10  B2  10  B2-300-10   5613.1656
11  B3  0   B3-300-0    5481.443
12  B3  5   B3-300-5    5603.2589
13  B3  10  B3-300-10   5603.402
14  B4  0   B4-300-0    5338.9765
15  B4  5   B4-300-5    5532.6854
16  B4  10  B4-300-10   5648.308
17  B5  0   B5-300-0    5678.463
18  B5  5   B5-300-5    5722.0628
19  B5  10  B5-300-10   5970.686
20          STD 3780.3707
21          STD 3782.0296
22          STD 3779.7178
23          STD 3766.577
24  B6  0   B6-300-0    9242.1142
25  B6  5   B6-300-5    8976.261
26  B6  10  B6-300-10   4260.6401
27  B7  0   B7-300-0    5491.4754
28  B7  5   B7-300-5    5539.7924
29  B7  10  B7-300-10   5504.2488
30  B8  0   B8-300-0    5558.7016
31  B8  5   B8-300-5    5714.8874
32  B8  10  B8-300-10   5521.0464
33  B9  0   B9-300-0    5767.7574
34  B9  5   B9-300-5    5695.7332
35  B9  10  B9-300-10   5687.0254
36  B10 0   B10-300-0   5337.9296
37  B10 5   B10-300-5   5422.4003
38  B10 10  B10-300-10  5382.5028
39          STD 3758.6318
40          STD 3755.0939
41          STD 3780.8918
42          STD 3772.1658
```

And then for the next block of samples (rows 24-38), I need to multiply each "CO2 area" value by the average of the STD samples before (rows 20-23) and after (rows 39-42) them, as well.

**The challenge** is that the layout of the standard gases (STD) and samples varies. I might have some results that have four STD gases, then 10 samples, then four STD gases, then 15 samples. In total, I need to calculate results for thousands of samples. I've been using excel, but it's a nightmare.

I'm new to programming and can't figure this one out. I use r and python. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you use `dput` to show the example in `R`

Comment: Something like this? https://gist.github.com/jlsgap/43eb3ceb6a13633a27c8d23f4672d8c1